# How can I send SMS messages from my mobile/router? (Linux/Textmode)

Tags: linux, modem, mobile, sms

I love mails sent to me from my own system, but I want more...

I want... for instance, texts about my system, and a little web-based SMS sender too. So, I buy a GSM (3G) router. This router can also send SMS messages, and here is my question:

Is there some (*commandline*) utility to use from Perl/Bash/PHP scripts to do so?

And no, I do *not* want to rely on a script that calls a free web-based SMS sender. I want to use *my* router, *my* number.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the GSM router, you should be able to use sms_serv from the  [smslink](http://smslink.sourceforge.net/) project.  I haven't tried this myself.

I was about to recommend looking at [this google voice perl script](http://www.0xdecafbad.com/2009/07/google-voice-command-line-script/) before I reread the question and saw you had the hardware...